# Problem when rebuild project in Android Studio when use Kotlin Class in Java Class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am a new developer in  Android Studio,
My Problem is when building my app using Kotlin Class in MainActivity Class, the error gives me not exists.

MainActivity is Java Code.
Other Classes are some Kotlin and some Java.

The picture below shows the error:
[image_url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHpjl.png)

```
C:\Users\ammar\AndroidStudioProjects\SPMBot\app\src\main\java\com\infinitytechno\spmbot\MainActivity.java:11: error: package com.infinitytechno.spmbot.background.services does not exist
import com.infinitytechno.spmbot.background.services.Actions;
                                                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

> `package com.infinitytechno.spmbot.background.services does not exist`

if com.infinitytechno.spmbot is your package name, check your project directory, make sure background and services is in the right order .

seems your project has some red error lines, fix them before build them.

Comment: I am already defined all of them, but these classes write in Kotlin Language, and the project is written in java language, I am checked 5 times and have the same problem.

Comment: You can try to delete the .idea .gradle file in the project directory, invitadate caches, and restart Android Studio.